# Assign JavaScript Geolocation to Variables - scoping issue?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, geolocation, es6-promise

Apologies is this is a duplicate, I have read similar threads but can't wrap my head around the issue, so hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to use the geolocation API to assign the users latitude, longitude and timestamp to a global variable (coords objet). I defined the function, and am able to console log out the result (from within the function in the 'success' callback), but cannot assign this to a variable (returns undefined).

In a util file:

```
const getLocation = () => {
    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    function success(pos) {
        const coords = {
            lat: pos.coords.latitude,
            long: pos.coords.longitude,
            time: pos.timestamp
        }
        return coords;
    }

    function error(err) {
        console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    }
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        return (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, 
    options));
    } else {
        return console.log('geolocation must be enabled')
    }};

export default getLocation;
```

Back in App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Weather from './components/Weather';
import getLocation from './services/getLocation';
//import getWeather from './services/getWeather';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Weather />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

console.log(getLocation())

export default App;
```

I suspect this is a scoping issue but can't seem to wrap my head around it. If anyone could offer some advice it would be amazing, thanks.